Fetch videos from Bunny.NET and dynamically publish on Squarespace
I want to upload hundreds of videos to squarespace website for customers to be able to preview and download them. If I would do it manually it would take me a very long time. Therefore I thought to make a script (chose python for now) to do it automatically. Using ChatGPT I was able to create such script but it doesnt seem to be working.
What I want it ideally to do is to fetch preview and embed code/link from Bunny.Net Stream for each video, embed it on squarespace with a direct download link on click (using Bunny.Net Storage). And do it for all of the videos I upload to bunny.net and embed them on the Squarespace website in a grid. The videos are vertical.
This is the code I managed to create and modify
import requests

# Function to fetch all video IDs from Bunny.net
def fetch_all_video_ids(api_key):
    url = 'https://api.bunny.net/videos'
    headers = {'AccessKey': api_key}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return [video['id'] for video in response.json()['videos']]

# Function to fetch video details from Bunny.net
def fetch_video_details(video_id, api_key):
    url = f'https://api.bunny.net/video/{video_id}/details'
    headers = {'AccessKey': api_key}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

# Function to publish video grid on Squarespace
def publish_video_grid_on_squarespace(video_details_list, squarespace_api_key, page_id):
    # Creating HTML for video grid
    video_grid_html = '<div class="video-grid">'
    for video_details in video_details_list:
        video_url = video_details['url']
        download_url = video_details['downloadUrl']
        video_grid_html += f'<div class="video-wrapper">'
        video_grid_html += f'<video src="{video_url}" controls>'
        video_grid_html += f'<a href="{download_url}" download>Download Video</a></video>'
        video_grid_html += '</div>'
    video_grid_html += '</div>'

    # Publishing video grid on Squarespace
    url = f'https://api.squarespace.com/1.0/{page_id}/collections'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {squarespace_api_key}'}
    data = {
        'type': 'html',
        'html': video_grid_html
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    return response.json()

# Main function
def main():
    # Set up your Bunny.net and Squarespace API credentials
    bunny_api_key = 'xxx'
    squarespace_api_key = 'xxx'
    squarespace_page_id = 'xxx'

    # Fetching all video IDs from Bunny.net
    bunny_video_ids = fetch_all_video_ids(bunny_api_key)

    # Fetching video details for each video and publishing video grid on Squarespace
    video_details_list = []
    for video_id in bunny_video_ids:
        video_details = fetch_video_details(video_id, bunny_api_key)
        video_details_list.append(video_details)

    response = publish_video_grid_on_squarespace(video_details_list, squarespace_api_key, squarespace_page_id)
    print("Video grid published on Squarespace:", response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This is the error command console shows me
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ervin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ervin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ervin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ervin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ervin\Desktop\publish_videos.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ervin\Desktop\publish_videos.py", line 48, in main
    bunny_video_ids = fetch_all_video_ids(bunny_api_key)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ervin\Desktop\publish_videos.py", line 8, in fetch_all_video_ids
    return [video['id'] for video in response.json()['videos']]
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ervin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Is this something someone done before or would be able to help me? Thank you!

you have error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) which means it gets empty data instead of JSON. Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

problem is response.json() - you expect to get JSON data but server doesn't send it. FIrst use print() to check response.text. Maybe server sends HTML with error message. And maybe this messsage will explain why it can't send JSON data.
